# In Excel, how to verify a column value is present in another column, but looking over multiple columns

Tags: excel

All I want to do is verify an exact phrase in a cell--over multiple columns--is present in another column cell.

For instance, say I had three name columns and one email column. I want to be able to write a function that looks over a row in the three name columns and, if that same row in the email column contains any of the exact phrases in the name columns, it will return true. Otherwise, return false. In this case, I basically just want to see if the email address has any of those exact names in it that the name columns have in its row.

The vlookup function, to my understanding, only lets you use one column in the lookup_value argument. Is there any way to look over multiple columns in there?

I appreciate any and all guidance.

Comment: Try `COUNTIFS` with wildcards `*`.

Answer (score 0):

I have an ugly solution for you.

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(FIND(B1,A1)),ISNUMBER(FIND(C1,A1)),ISNUMBER(FIND(D1,A1))),True,False)
```

[Screen Cap, since I can't embed images yet apparently.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64ulg.png)

The Find functions break the logic for the OR function, so the ISNUMBER function takes the #VALUE! and return False. I would have preferred COUNTIFS, but the wildcard search that worked with COUNTIF broke under COUNTIFS, so I went a different direction.

Comment: Thank you for this! I've tested your solution and it will work for my project. I really appreciate your help!!